# error:Unable to load config class while running the codegen cli jar spec version 3.x

Tags: swagger-codegen

I am trying to run the codegen jar for my swagger spec. But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't load config class with name jaxrs Available: dynamic-html
html
html2
java
jaxrs-cxf-client
jaxrs-cxf
inflector
jaxrs-cxf-cdi
jaxrs-spec
jaxrs-jersey
jaxrs-di
jaxrs-resteasy-eap
jaxrs-resteasy
spring
kotlin-client
kotlin-server
php
swift3
swift4
typescript-angular

        at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:31)
        at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jaxrs
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at io.swagger.codegen.CodegenConfigLoader.forName(CodegenConfigLoader.java:29)
        ... 1 more
Press any key to exit
sh: __git_ps1: command not found
```

I am using codegen jar version 3.0.x. I tried it with different version like 3.0.0, 3.0.1,3.0.2,3.0.23.For all the error is same, only the langauage differs listed above. For drafting the swagger I have used "openapi: 3.0.2".
Please give your valuable inputs.

Comment: Post the command line that you used to run the codegen

Comment: @Helen, To generate the stub I have used this command: sh swagger-generation-v1.sh

Comment: Post the contents of your `swagger-generation-v1.sh` script.